# Variance of probability distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have continuous distribution, $X$,  with probability density function
$$f_X(x) = \frac{\alpha{\beta}^\alpha}{(x+\beta)^{\alpha+1}}$$
where $\alpha > 1, \beta > 0, x \ge 0$. I have also found the expected value to be
$$E(X) = \alpha\beta\left(\frac{1}{\alpha-1}-\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$$

I am required to obtain the **variance** of the distribution and I am very stuck on doing this? I know that
$$Var(X) = E(X^2)-E^2(X)$$
but got stuck funding $E(X^2)$.

Comment: $E[X^2]=\int_{0}^{+\infty}x^2f_X(x)dx$. Did you try this and it did not work?

Comment: I just tried it. It seems that the integral doesn't exist for $\alpha <= 2$ ?

Comment: Since you have $x^2/(x+β)^{α+1}$, for this to exist you must have $a+1-2>1\iff a>2$. So, yes, what you say is correct.

Comment: @JimmyR. Does that mean that the variance does not exist for $1<a<=2$ but the expectation does? And that both expectation and variance exist for a > 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly. But wait for the gurus in here to confirm this, sometimes I am wrong.